# Previous commits showing git LFS pointers instead of file diff

Tags: git, git-lfs

My git repository has some git-lfs managed files. I was getting some errors with git lfs and I was trying to fix them.

Unknowingly I ran
`git lfs migrate import`.

I ran into an issue now where all the files in my repository are git lfs managed and if I do a git show on any previous commit, I get the git lfs pointer instead of actual file diff.

I did a `git lfs install` and `git lfs pull`. This fixed the files but git show on the old commits still shows pointers instead of actual file diff. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I needed to undo the `git lfs migrate import`

To do this, I ran `git reflog` and then `git reset --hard HASH` to a previous point.